# Devops Community: How do you build catalog of multiple services?

Tags: devops, versioning, catalog

We have got around 80 micro-services in our product. We make quarterly release of our product. In order to identify which version of service is going on which release, we maintain a manifest file in every release. Our manifest files are growing dramatically and we don't like it.

- Is there a better way to maintain this catalog?
- Have you used any tool which helps you maintaining this application catalog?